# Creating log with millisecond portion in time

Tags: c#

I am writing activities of a program in a log with timestamp attached to each line with the following format:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss FFF")
```

I was expecting the millisecond portion to always have 3 digits. However the following appears:

```
11/29/2013 18:53:14 96 -  SessionKey-2rvun1agyw1svcexmqf5dejh-MAC.Master Page_Load - Begin
11/29/2013 18:53:14 975 -  SessionKey-2rvun1agyw1svcexmqf5dejh-MAC.Master Page_Load - End
```

In the first one, why is the millisecond portion not 096?

Comment: probably because of [leading zeros](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leading_zero)

Comment: It works just as described in MSDN pages. google helps.

Comment: @Akshay J, are you sure you wrote `hh:mm:ss` intentionally? Because it will produce 06:53:14 instead of 18:53:14.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss fff"
```

Comment: `FFF` on my machine gives `096`, it's probably culture specific

Comment: `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` `en-US`

Comment: I set my culture to `en-US` and it didn't work. `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");Print(dt.ToString("FFF"));` prints `05`

Comment: try to pass culture as second parameter.

Comment: @IlyaIvanov try to set the milliseconds part to `960` whith `FF` it should be `96` and with `fff` it should be `960`. You're confusing leading zeros with trailing zeros.

Answer (score 4):

From The [`"FFF" Custom Format Specifier`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#FFF_Specifier)

> The "FFF" custom format specifier represents the three most
>   significant digits of the seconds fraction; that is, it represents the
>   milliseconds in a date and time value. **However, trailing zeros or
>   three zero digits are not displayed.**

**EDIT**: Ok, I think I figure out what's going on here. In original, OP's millisecond part is `960` not `096`.

That's why it is working exactly how describes in *MSDN* page.

It's trailing `0` at the end of `960`, it is not leading `0` in `096`.

As a solution, you can use [`The "fff" Custom Format Specifier`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#fffSpecifier) instead. It doesn't trail or leading zeros in my opinion. At least it doesn't write in *MSDN* page `:)`

**EDIT2**: I think people are confusing what is [*trailing zero*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trailing_zero) and *[leading zero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leading_zero)*

From Wikipedia pages;

> ## Trailing zero
>
> In mathematics, trailing zeros are a sequence of 0s in
>   the decimal representation (or more generally, in any positional
>   representation) of a number, **after which no other digits follow**.

---

> ## Leading zero
>
> A leading zero is any 0 digit that leads a number string
>   in positional notation. **For example, James Bond's famous identifier,
>   007, has two leading zeros**.

Comment: Well, on that same page results for `date1.ToString("hh:mm:ss.FFF", ci)` and `date1.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff", ci)` are identical - `Displays 07:27:15.018`

Comment: And both have CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

Comment: @AkshayJ so probably the best suggestion is to use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` as second parameter of `ToString`

Comment: Who is getting confused ? I always talked about leading zeros.

Comment: @AkshayJ I think your millisecond part is `960` not `096` in your first example. This is trailing zeros, not leading zeros..

Comment: I need the millisecond part should always have 3 digits and if they are just 2 digits like 98 ms, it should be denoted as 098 and not as 98. What should I use ?

Comment: @AkshayJ `fff` format looks like okey for you, isn't it? It shows `098` not `98` for example.

Answer (score 0):

on my machine:

```
hh:mm:ss.fff  leading zeros
hh:mm:ss.FFF  NO leading zeros
```

sample code:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 2222; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss fff"));
    }
    string input;
    input = Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: **Trailing zeros**, not leading zeros. Leading zeros are important.

Comment: Please explain: 94 -> 094 with leading zeroes, thats not the same as 94 -> 940!!!

Comment: That´s what the Q was, about LEADING zeroes

Comment: The question was not about leading zeros, you said "hh:mm:ss.FFF  NO leading zeros" try with `ms = 96`, this would print (with FFF) `096`! See trailing zeros preserved! You should have said `hh:mm:ss.fff trailing zeros` and `hh:mm:ss.FFF  NO trailing zeros`

Comment: See Soner Gönül's answer